# viewport Mozile Firefox не работает

Tags: viewport

Столкнулся с такой проблемой - уже все перекопал в Интернете - найти решения не могу ... 
Не работает viewport в Firefox. 
В Хроме все работает отлично после расширение 320px идет отдаление от экрана , а когда сужаешь в Firefox - идет боковой скролл ( Отдаление не происходит ) . Может кто то сталкивался с такой проблемой . 
Не спрашивайте зачем нужно отдаление после 320px - так просит заказчик ...

Спасибо большое...

Comment: А что вы понимаете под «viewport»? Метатег? Css?

Comment: <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1,  maximum-scale = 1, , min-width=320"> 

В данный момент установлен вот такой viewport - может так понятней будет - если я не правильно выразился ...